# Sumatra PDF Forward and Inverse search emacs

Tags: compiling, emacs, sumatrapdf

I have spent so much time trying to find a way to do both forward and inverse search on Emacs-Sumatra on a windows 10 computer.

Whenever I do C-c C-c, I would like to be sent to the part of the PDF that corresponds to where I have the cursor at that time. Likewise, I'd like to be able to "Shift+click" on Sumatra ad be sent to that line of code on Emacs.

On the init.el I have:

```lisp
;;==================== LaTeX ====================

;; =============== Basic Settings =================

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)

(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save
(setq TeX-auto-local ".emacs.c/auto/") ; Directory for autosaves
(setq TeX-save-query nil) ;; autosave before compiling

(setq TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript t) ;; Automatic script braces
(setq TeX-electric-math (cons "$" "$")) ;; Automatic dollars

(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")

(setq TeX-PDF-mode t) ;; set default to PDF-LaTeX
(setq-default TeX-master nil) ;; ask everytime for default master-file

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)

;;---------------- Interactive Sumatra ---------------

(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(setq TeX-view-program-list
   '(("Sumatra PDF" ("\"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance"
                      (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search %b %n ") " %o"))))
(eval-after-load 'tex
  '(progn
     (assq-delete-all 'output-pdf TeX-view-program-selection)
     (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Sumatra PDF"))))
(server-start)
```

And in Sumatra I have:

```
CheckForUpdates = true
RememberOpenedFiles = true
InverseSearchCmdLine = "C:\Emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -n +%l "%f"
EnableTeXEnhancements = true
DefaultDisplayMode = automatic
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? I am about to write a very long document and being able to do this kind of search seems rather crucial.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if sumatra does what you need but I think that you can view pdf docment and do inverse search with emacs with no need of sumatra

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX are you using?  And what happens if you hit `C-c C-v` after `C-c C-c`?

Comment: In your Sumatra advanced settings ReuseInstance should be set true thus no need to complicate the forward search with -reuse-instance just remove it also in SumatraPDF I think use tabs needs to be true certainly set HighlightPermanent = true then you can see the results more easily Important the command I use to go to PDF is C-c C-v    And to jump back to line in buffer it is  **Double click** not control

Comment: Right, so I am using AUCTeX 12.1.1. Whenever I use C-c C-v after C-c C-c, I just see the document.
The ReuseInstance worked though!!! Thank you so much KJO!!! Now I can do inverse search. However, when I do C-c C-c I am not sent to the position where the cursor is, although, now I have it highlighted. Any ideas why?

Comment: Synctex in contrast to its name is **rarely 1 on 1** In most editors the compile & jump are often linked so if your on last line of tex paragraph you may see pdf open with paragraph highlighted, equally when in pdf double click an included text and depending how it is set-up may jump back to tex in sub file or \include in main. In default auctex  tex to pdf forward is C-c C-**v** iew (for most users)  but some users change it by altering C-c C-c. Editors like texshop use "hinting" to jump with precision from tex to pdf word by word. Please edit question to clarify where you currently stand.

Comment: So,now something really strange is happening. For a document called **thesis.tex**, I can perfectly do inverse and forward searches. Everything is fine with it but for another document, named **SlicedWeylMetric.tex**, the inverse search doesn't work.
At times I get an alert that I don't know if is related 'cause inverse search still works with thesis.tex...
"Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server.
There is an existing Emacs server, named "server".
To start the server in this Emacs process, stop the existing
server or call ‘M-x server-force-delete’ to forcibly d"

Comment: There are many ways synctex (the component that builds files to cross index locations between tex input and pdf output) can trip up, the filenames and their paths must be fairly plain and simple (avoid spaces accents punctuation) the background call forwards or backwards must be well defined or else the receiving app will try to open a second / alternative copy. Set-up can be a minefield but once stable it is a benefit. a common issue can be the other secondary files such as .aux or .synctex from one run may not be correctly replaced on the next.

Comment: Indeed. At the end I realised it was because I was missing a **-synctex=1** in the following definition of Latexmk so I was not actually producing the synctex... 
My init.el now contains:

(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (add-to-list
    'TeX-command-list
    `("Latexmk"
      ,(concat "latexmk -pdf -bibtex -synctex=1 %s")
      TeX-run-TeX nil t :help "Run Latexmk"))))